# Connecting and displaying Raspberry Pi on Ubuntu based machine over ethernet cable

Tags: ssh, display, ubuntu, connection, laptop

Hello dear Raspberry community. I was wondering if I could display Raspberry  Pi 3 Model B on my Ubuntu laptop over an Ethernet cable? However, I can not do it with an ssh method, the reason being I have once connected it to the TV and installed the OS already.

So, all I need to do is just over an Ethernet cable and with the help of some other software's (in Ubuntu of course) to connect, see, and use my devices on the Raspberry. Any tutorials, or help are deeply appreciated!

Comment: Your question make very little sense to me... Why exactly do you think you `can not do it with an ssh method`? You can run and programs showing terminal output using SSH while you view a GUI on your TV showing something else.

Answer (score 3):

You can always use **ssh** if it is enabled on the RasPi, no matter if the RasPi is connected to a TV or not. How to enable **ssh** look at [SSH (Secure Shell)](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/remote-access/ssh/) and [SSH using Linux or Mac OS](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/remote-access/ssh/unix.md). If you want to have a full graphical user interface with windows you can use **VNC**. How to do it look at [VNC (Virtual Network Computing)](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/remote-access/vnc/README.md).